# Tempfile generation with different pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, temporary-files

I'm creating a Tempfile like this

```
Tempfile.new("myfile.txt")
```

This creates a file like this

```
TempDir/myfile.txt20120210-1696-yd53si
```

but I need it to create it like this

```
TempDir/20120210-1696-yd53si/myfile.txt
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a tmpdir, not a tmpfile.

```
require 'tmpdir'
puts Dir.mktmpdir('') #the empty string means : no prefix
#=>"/tmp/20120210-9462-kzrkxx"
```

Comment: when I dereference the file, is it going to be automatically garbage collected?

Comment: Yes, like (almost) all objects. The OS will keep the file open if you don't close it first though.

Comment: I mean the file itself. will it be deleted once dereferenced? (since it's in a temp dir)

Comment: so what's the difference between a tempdir and a normal dir?